# Help with improper integrals containing partial fractions

Tags: integration, limits, improper-integrals, partial-fractions

Specifically,
$$\int_1^\infty \frac {24}{8x(x+1)^2} dx$$
and
$$\int_3^\infty \frac {1}{t^2 - 2t} dt$$

Both of these problems are supposed to converge, but I keep getting infinity in my answer.  For the first one, I have $$3 \lim_{b\to \infty}\left( \ln x - ln(x+1) + \frac{1}{x+1}\right)  \biggm|_{1}^b $$  and for the second I have $$\frac12 \lim_{b\to \infty} \left(\ln(t-2) - \ln(t)\right)  \biggm|_{3}^b  $$  Did I make a mistake up to that point or am I missing something with the limits?  The first answer should be $0.578$ and the second $\frac12 \ln 3$

Comment: Combine the 2 $\ln$ expressions by using $\ln a-\ln b = \ln\frac{a}{b}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice,

1) $$3\lim_{b\to \infty}\left(\ln x-\ln(x+1)+\frac{1}{x+1}\right) \biggm|_{1}^{b}=3\lim_{b\to \infty}\left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac1x}\right)+\frac{1}{x+1}\right) \biggm|_{1}^{b}$$

$$=3\lim_{b\to \infty}\left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac 1b}\right)+\frac{1}{b+1}-\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
$$=3\left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{1+0}\right)+0+\ln\left(2\right)-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
$$=3\left(\ln\left(2\right)-\frac{1}{2}\right)=\color{red}{3\ln 2-\frac{3}{2}}$$

2) $$\frac{1}{2}\lim_{b\to \infty}\left(\ln (t-2)-\ln t\right) \biggm|_{3}^{b}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{b\to \infty}\ln\left(\frac{t-2}{t}\right) \biggm|_{3}^{b}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{b\to \infty}\ln\left(1-\frac{2}{t}\right) \biggm|_{3}^{b}$$

$$=\frac12\lim_{b\to \infty}\left(\ln\left(1-\frac{2}{b}\right)-\ln\left(1-\frac{2}{3}\right)\right)$$
$$=\frac12\left(\ln\left(1-0\right)-\ln\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\right)$$
$$=\frac12\left(0+\ln(3)\right)=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}\ln 3}$$

Answer (score 2):

You did not make any mistakes, the thing you're missing with the limits is that $\ln a-\ln b=\ln\frac{a}{b}$.

Evaluate the limit, noting that $\ln x \to 0$ as $x \to 1$:
$$3\lim_{b\to \infty}\left( \ln x - ln(x+1) + \frac{1}{x+1}\right) \biggm|_{1}^b $$
$$= 3\lim_{b\to \infty}\left( \ln \frac{x}{x+1} + \frac{1}{x+1}\right) \biggm|_{1}^b $$
$$= 3\lim_{b\to \infty}\left( \ln \frac{b}{b+1} + \frac{1}{b+1} - \ln \frac{1}{1+1} - \frac{1}{1+1}\right) $$
$$= 3\left( 0 + 0 - \ln \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\right) $$
$$= 3\ln 2 - \frac{3}{2}$$
Using the same method, the second limit can be evaluated.

Comment: Why does the limit as b approaches infinity of ln(b/(b+1)) = 0?  Do you use l'hopital's rule inside the ln?

Comment: @AustinFreeman Since $\frac{b}{b+1} \to 1$ as $b \to \infty$ and $\ln 1 = 0$. You _can_ use L'Hospital's rule but that would be quite unnecessary. If you use it, you would still have to take out the $\ln$ in order to put it in the form $\lim \frac{a}{b}$. Either way, $\lim \ln \frac{b}{b+1} = \ln \lim \frac{b}{b+1} = \ln 1 = 0 $.

Comment: Ah. I didn't know you could take the ln outside the limit.  Thanks!